# open-wc how to use web components in a legacy application

Tags: web-component, lit-element

I had a look at the open-wc generator. I can generate web component libraries and web component application but the generated README file and the documentation does not contain a description how to import a web component library into another library or into an application so that the library or application can use the dependency as a web component. Is there a sample but non trivial application build with open-wc that I can use to learn from?

My primary interest is to import several web component into a legacy application that does not use npm and rollup by itself. What would be the best way to do that?

What I have tried to do. I have created a library litelement-demo by running

```
npm init @open-wc
```

and I have created an application in the similar way. I have opted for using typescript in both cases. The README.md of libelement-demo states that it can be used in this way:

```
<script type="module">
  import 'litelement-demo/litelement-demo.js';
</script>

<litelement-demo></litelement-demo>
```

I have added this snippet to the application's index.html and run

```
npm i --save ../litelement-demo
npm run build
```

but the 2nd command fails with the error message

```
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
litelement-demo/litelement-demo.js (imported by inline-module-index-1.js)
```

The link in the error message does not help and neither the open webcomponent documentation nor the generated README.md files.

Answer (score 0):

Typical web component is basically a class as follows:

```
// You can also use some external library and inherit from its base class.
// For example: LitElement
class BasicSetup extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    // Template/DOM generation
  }

  // One or more methods...
}

// Registration
customElements.define('basic-setup', BasicSetup);
```

Have a look at a registration statement. Simply add this file in your HTML `scripts` section and you are done. You do not have to integrate with any existing library or solution. Wherever, you have HTML, you can simply use it as

```
<div>
  <p>My Awesome web component</p>
  <basic-setup></basic-setup>
</div>
```

You can also initialize the element with JavaScript using `customElements.get(name)` method if you do not have access to `BasicSetup` class reference.

```
// Get reference to basic-setup class assuming it is already registred.
const ClassRef = customElements.get('basic-setup');

// Initialize using constructor
const myCustomElm = new ClassRef();

// or use document.createElement
const myCustomElm = document.createElement('basic-setup');

document.body.appendChild(myCustomElm);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have extended my question to make it more clear what kind of problem I have. My web component is working fine in isolation but I cannot find out how to integrate it in an application based on the open webcomponent tooling.

Answer (score 0):

Since your legacy application doesn't use npm, you don't need to do anything with it an npm.

Just add  in the head

```
<script type="module">
  import 'litelement-demo/litelement-demo.js';
</script>
```

and then use

```
<litelement-demo></litelement-demo>
```

somewhere in your html. Nothing else needed to start working

Comment: But I would not have the advantages of the bundler. I have to host the litelement library and other dependencies by myself somewhere.